# Thread safety while calling cython shared library from C

Tags: python, c, multithreading, thread-safety, cython

I am trying to replace some old legacy 'C' api code that is currently not thread safe. That said, I also want a future for it in python since none of the team will ever learn 'C' (to the point of confidently modifying the code).

My plan is to create a thin abstraction in 'C' using the existing legacy code and calling cython code to make SOAP webservice requests. The expected setup is something like:

```
ThirdPartySoftware -> 
    C-Legacy-turned-into-Wrapper (shared library) -> 
       Cython-generated-webservice client (shared library)
```

**Question**: Can this be made thread safe?

Reason I ask is after reading about GIL I am confused whether usage of 'requests' library (or similar other options) will force me to single-thread the webservice calls.

Thanks